# Is RegNotifyChangeKeyValue as coarse as it seems?

Tags: winapi, registry, notify

I've been using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to monitor a particular portion of the file system. It rather nicely provides a partial pathname to the file or directory which changed along with a clue about the nature of the change. This may have spoiled me.

I also need to monitor a particular portion of the registry, but it looks as if `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` is very coarse. It will tell me that **something** under the given key changed, but it doesn't seem to want to tell me what that something might have been. Bummer!

The portion of the registry in question is arbitrarily deep, so enumerating all the sub-keys and calling `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` for each probably isn't a hot idea because I'll eventually end up having to overcome `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`. Plus I'd have to adjust the set of keys I'd passed to `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`, which would be a fair amount of effort to do without enumerating the sub-keys every time, which would defeat a fair amount of the purpose.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes.  You probably have to cache all the values of interest to your code, and update this cache yourself whenever you get a change trigger, or else set up multiple watchers, one on each of the individual data items of interest. As you noted the second solution gets unwieldy very quickly.

If you can implement the required code in .Net you can get the same effect more elegantly via [RegistryEvent and its subclasses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393043%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).